# Laravel 4.2 non-ambiguous named routes in group

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have the following code in routes.php:

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'dev/order'], function() {
            Route::get('create', ['as' => 'dev.order.create', 'uses' => 'OrderController@create']);
            Route::get('create-pack', ['as' => 'dev.order.create-pack', 'uses' => 'OrderController@createPack']);
        }
    );
```

How can I get rid of duplicate action name, 'dev.order' and 'OrderController' substrings in parameters? Route::controller() and Route::resource() creates unnamed routes when viewed via

```
php artisan routes
```

While I need a group of named routes to one controller with common prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, there is no route name prefix yet in Laravel, so, to remove repetition of strings, you can do things like this:

```
$prefix = 'dev.order.';
$controller = 'OrderController@';

Route::group(['prefix' => 'dev/order'], function() use ($prefix, $prefix)
{
    Route::get('create', ['as' => $prefix.'create', 'uses' => $controller.'create']);
    Route::get('create-pack', ['as' => $prefix.'create-pack', 'uses' => $controller.'createPack']);
});
```